# How to convert syntax from Foxpro to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, visual-foxpro, foxpro

```
LOCAL  in_txt
in_txt='mohammad'
txt_len=LEN(in_txt)
rev_txt=''

FOR ii=1 TO txt_len
w_chr=SUBSTR(in_txt,ii,1)
w_asc=IIF(ASC(w_chr)=32,32,ASC(w_chr)+1)
*    ?'    #'+w_chr+'='+CHR(w_asc)+'*'+STR(ASC(w_chr))+'>'+STR(ASC(w_chr)+1)+'*'+CHR(ASC(w_chr))+'>'+CHR(ASC(w_chr)+1)


rev_txt=rev_txt+ CHR(w_asc)
ENDFOR 

return rev_txt
```

---

I understand solve my problem * character is using comment in foxpro.

Comment: Instead of converting the code (which would require the help of someone that is familiar with both products), why don't you post sample data and desired result, so that those of us not familiar with foxpro can also help?

Comment: I don't understand this line *    ?'    #'+w_chr+'='+CHR(w_asc)+'*'+STR(ASC(w_chr))+'>'+STR(ASC(w_chr)+1)+'*'+CHR(ASC(w_chr))+'>'+CHR(ASC(w_chr)+1)

Comment: I have no idea. I'm good with SQL Server, never worked with foxpro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the equivalent SQL

```
DECLARE @in_txt varchar(100)
DECLARE @txt_Len int
DECLARE @rev_txt varchar(100)=''
DECLARE @i int=0
DECLARE @w_chr char(1)
DECLARE @w_asc int

SET @in_txt='mohammad'
SET @txt_len=LEN(@in_txt)

WHILE @i < @txt_len
BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1
    SET @w_chr=SUBSTRING(@in_txt,@i,1)
    SET @w_asc = ASCII(@w_chr)
    IF @w_asc <> 32 SET @w_asc=@w_asc+1
    PRINT '#'+@w_chr+'='+CHAR(@w_asc)+'*'+STR(ASCII(@w_chr))+'>'+STR(ASCII(@w_chr)+1)+'*'+CHAR(ASCII(@w_chr))+'>'+CHAR(ASCII(@w_chr)+1)
    SET @rev_txt = @rev_txt + CHAR(@w_asc)

END

PRINT @rev_Txt
```

It appears to be a very simple encryption of the text.  The Print statement in the loop (which is the equivalent of the ? in Foxpro) is the debugger statement

Comment: You were close. It would be 32 not 31 and varbinary instead of varchar.

Comment: Fixed the typo for you

Comment: Thanks but still it should be binary.

Answer (score 0):

It is a badly written piece of VFP code. * marks the line as a comment and basically it is replacing all the characters in the string except the char 32 (SPACE) with the next in ASCII chart. That is not something you could easily convert in MS SQL though, because in VFP a string could have any character in it including char(0). Assuming you don't have char 0:

```
Declare @in_txt varbinary(MAX);
DECLARE @rev_txt varbinary(MAX);
set @in_txt = CAST('mohammad' AS VARBINARY(MAX));
declare @i int;
declare @w_char int;
set @i = 1;
SET @rev_txt = CAST('' AS VARBINARY(MAX));

WHILE @i <= Len(@in_txt)
Begin
   set @w_char = ASCII(SUBSTRING(@in_txt,@i,1));
   SET @rev_txt = @rev_txt + 
    CAST(@w_char + case when @w_char = 32 then 0 else 1 end AS BINARY(1));
   SET @i = @i +1;
END
SELECT @rev_txt;
```